# How to run python code with params using Java, ./AdafruitDHT.py 22 4

Tags: java, python

*Hello. I'm trying to set raspbian to work with sensors (like DHT22 temperature&humidity) ones. Found library with drivers wrote in Python https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT
and installed into my Raspberry 3 B+ with necessary librares to work.
To run this sensor via LXTerminal have to type*

```
cd /home/pi/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples
./AdafruitDHT.py 22 4
```

*these numbers are params need to work :
22 specify which controller im using now, like 22 - DHT22,
4 specify which GPIO pin of raspberrypi im using now*

*All its fine as long im using this way, returns "Temp=20.1° Humidity=59.8%". But need to put these console lines into simple java program to work. Found something close to it like this script*

## Test.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        //Build command
        List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();
        commands.add("./Adafruit.py");
        //Add arguments
        commands.add("22 4");
        System.out.println(commands);

        //Run macro on target
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
        pb.directory(new File("/home/pi/Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples"));
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process = pb.start();

        //Read output
        StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line = null, previous = null;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            if (!line.equals(previous)) {
                previous = line;
                out.append(line).append('\n');
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        //Check result
        if (process.waitFor() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Success!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //Abnormal termination: Log command parameters and output and throw ExecutionException
        System.err.println(commands);
        System.err.println(out.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

*At this way i know it actually works path part and partly AdafruitDHT.py (it returns string to use proper command, like*

```
./AdafruitDHT.py 22 4
```

*i cant do something like*

```
commands.add("./Adafruit.py 22 4");
```

*because it return that theres no programm like this one.*

**Long story short - need to reedit this code to work propertly with params im adding, but...
...there's actually second way to fix it, but need to reedit this AdafruitDHT.py file to get constant params (22 4) but don't know how to do it.
Script contains code:**

## AdafruitDHT.py

```
import sys

import Adafruit_DHT


# Parse command line parameters. sensor_args = { 
                '11': Adafruit_DHT.DHT11,
                '22': Adafruit_DHT.DHT22,
                '2302': Adafruit_DHT.AM2302 } if len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1] in sensor_args:
    sensor = sensor_args[sys.argv[1]]
    pin = sys.argv[2] else:
    print('usage: sudo ./Adafruit_DHT.py [11|22|2302] GPIOpin#')
    print('example: sudo ./Adafruit_DHT.py 2302 4 - Read from an AM2302 connected to GPIO #4')
    sys.exit(1)

# Try to grab a sensor reading.  Use the read_retry method which will retry up
# to 15 times to get a sensor reading (waiting 2 seconds between each retry). humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)

# Un-comment the line below to convert the temperature to Fahrenheit.
# temperature = temperature * 9/5.0 + 32

# Note that sometimes you won't get a reading and
# the results will be null (because Linux can't
# guarantee the timing of calls to read the sensor).
# If this happens try again! if humidity is not None and temperature is not None:
    print('Temp={0:0.1f}*  Humidity={1:0.1f}%'.format(temperature, humidity)) else:
    print('Failed to get reading. Try again!')
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this one script is working ;)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] command = new String[]{"/home/pi/Desktop/dht22/examples/AdafruitDHT.py","22","4"};

        Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
        try {
            proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.print(line + "\n");
        }

        try {
            proc.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```